# How to make forward the address pointer of ARM register while passing array of elements as parameter in an assembly function

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, arm, neon

Being a novice developer in the field of assembly language, I am trying to write several arm neon functions to speed up calculations. I am going to attach two code fragments to explain my question.

```
void CalculateSumOfLast64(unsigned int *pData, unsigned int *ans)
{
    unsigned int *pDataTemp = pData + 192;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++){
        sum += pDataTemp[i];
    }
    *ans = sum;
}
int main(){
    unsigned int *pData = new unsigned int[256]; //Always Length is 256
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
        pData[i] = rand()%256;
    }
    unsigned int *ans = new unsigned int[1];
    CalculateSumOfLast64(pData, ans);
    cout<<"Final Ans = "<<*ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am trying to calculate summation of last 64 values from an array of elements. I have converted this function by the use of arm neon instruction sets.

```
NEON_ASM_FUNC_BEGIN CalculateSumOfLast64_ARM_NEON
#r0 First parameter, This is the address of <pData>
#r1 Second Parameter, This is the address of <ans>
push {r2-r8, lr}
mov r4, r0

mov r5, #192
.skipLoop:
vld1.u32 {d0}, [r4]!
subs r5, #2
bne .skipLoop

mov r8, #0
mov r5, #64
.calculationLoop:
vld1.u32 {d0}, [r4]!
vmov r7, r6, d0
add r8, r8, r6;
add r8, r8, r7;
subs r5, #2
bne .calculationLoop

str r8, [r1]
pop {r2-r8, pc}
NEON_ASM_FUNC_END
```

It's really easy to move forward or manipulate address pointer in c++.

```
unsigned int *pDataTemp = pData + 192;
```

I needed an entire loop to move the address pointer in arm register.

```
mov r5, #192
.skipLoop:
vld1.u32 {d0}, [r4]!
subs r5, #2
bne .skipLoop
```

Though this solution is working, I know... it's definitely not a good idea. 
I am searching a lot on web to come up with a solution. 
Is there any instruction set to make forward the address pointer of arm register??
Or, is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried just `add r4, r4, r5, LSL #1`?

Comment: I think this instruction will work like:  
r4 = ( r4 + r5 ) * 2. 
Actually I need different arm instruction to move the address pointer.

Comment: That is incorrect. It works like `r4 = r4 + r5 * 2`, which seems to be what you want. Note that if you just want to advance `r4` by 192 positions, you could just do `add r4,r4,#768`.

Comment: @fuz, Yes, you are right. add r4, r4, r5, LSL #1 instruction works like, r4 = r4 + r5 * 2.
But the instruction, add r4, r4, #768 seems r4 = r4 + 768. 
Are you sure it will advance the register address by 192 positions. I am little bit confused, because I don't understand how it will work. would you please explain?

Comment: 192 * 4 = 768. Memory is addressable by single byte, while your elements are 4 bytes long, so to move by 192 element positions you have to increase the address by 4*192.  (BTW, can't the compiler be set up to use neon instructions and vectorization optimization steps? It will very likely produce something faster (or more correct) than you)

Comment: Ok, the number 768 is the total bytes to advance. 
But in this case, add r4,r4,#768 seems it will increase the value by 768 which the register r4 currently pointing to.. 
Please clarify me if I am wrong.

Comment: `r4` is content of register `r4`, which is 32 bit value. `[r4]` is memory content, addressed by `r4` value (so in this case `r4` is interpreted as memory address). In `add r4,r4,#768` the 32 bits of `r4` are interpreted and used as 32 bit integer numeric value, so if there was address pointing to first element of array (in C `pData + 0` value), then 768 will be added to it, which is in C like `(int*)(((byte*)pData) + 768)`. Which is equal to `pData + 192` if `pData` is of `int*` type. The C does "help" with pointer arithmetic by using the known data type size to multiply the index. Asm doesn't

Comment: Actually IIRC the ARM doesn't even have `add` to memory, like `add [r4],[r4],#768`, you always have to (with common RISC-like instructions, not sure what neon extension offers, maybe that operates also over memory content) fetch the value from memory, then do the arithmetic in registers only, and store the result back into memory.

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks for your wonderful explanation. Now it's totally clear to me.

Comment: One more thing. You don't have to preserve r0-r4 regardless of the number of arguments. That's the protocol. Change push/pop accordingly. ({r4-r8, lr/pc})

Comment: But are you aware what you are doing? Why do you load values to NEON registers if they are to be computed on ARM? Transferring from NEON to ARM registers will slow down the system terribly. (14 cycles each time). Even a Java routine doing the same will be faster by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just move, but add in the beginning:

```
add r4, r0, #192*4
```

That will do.

Answer (score 1):

**Example in C++:**
It's really easy to move forward or manipulate address pointer in c++.

```
void testFunc(unsigned int *pData)
{
//Move address if needed...and do calculations.. 
unsigned int *pDataNew = pData + 192;
}
```

**Example in Assembly:**
In assembly we can perform the operation in following instruction set.

```
ADD R7, R0, #192*4
```

**Explanation:**
This instruction can be used in adding values and adding memory addresses
*i)* Let's consider R0 register represents a value.
 For example, R0 = 598.
 Then **ADD R7, R0, #192*4** instruction will work like
 **R7 = 598 + 192 * 4 = 1366**.
R7 will represent another value. 


*ii)* Let's consider R0 register represents a memory address.
 For example, **R0 =  0xcbc02150**(Memory Address depending on ARCH).
 Then **ADD R7, R0, #192*4** instruction will work like
 **R7 = 0xCBC02150 + HexValue(192*4) = 0xCBC02150 + 0x300 = 0xCBC02450**.
 R7 will represent another memory address.

Comment: Adding integers vs. adding pointers *isn't* a "different task".  In assembly language, pointers are just integers.  (Also, the addresses in your example are 48-bit, which is weird.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, Thanks for for the review. I have edited the answer following your suggestion. :)

Comment: Great. I gave you the most correct answer long time ago, you answer your own, and pick it. Now you can guess: Will I be answering your questions in the future?

Comment: @Jake Alquimista Lee , Sorry Bro... I didn't mean to hurt you. I just tried to elaborate the answer with some explanation. I have just accepted your answer. :)